# Change text on a View Controller through Table View Controller options?

Tags: ios, iphone

I am designing an iOS 7 iPhone app in Xcode with Table View controller with various Table View Cells. I am trying to make is so that one View Controller is displayed whenever you click on any of the Table View Cells but changes the View Controller's text to something different depending on which option the user selects on the Table View. I already have a setup that working which requires a different View controller for every single option but that is inefficient and a complete mess. Any ideas? (I am a Java programmer and completely new to iOS...). Thanks!

Comment: In Xcode, create a new app using the "Master-Detail" template. That does more or less what you describe, and should be helpful as a starting point.

Answer (score 0):

What you describe is very close to the Master Detail template iOS app, so you should create that in Xcode and study it to see how it works. You probably would only need to make some tweaks to it to make it function how you want it to.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps if you add a property to the header file of the UIViewController subclass you wish to display, like:

```
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSString *customText;
```

Then, in `didSelectRowAtIndexPath`, set the `customText` attribute before showing the view controller. Inside the view controller, use `self.customText` to display it.

I hope this is useful!